# Error: #1146 - Table 'information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just installed phpmyadmin 4.0.8.  Am trying to use it to access 4.1.20 database running on Linux.  When I attempt to log into the database server using phpmyadmin, I get this error:

> SELECT * FROM information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS

MySQL said:

> Documentation
>
> ## 1146 - Table 'information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS' doesn't exist

Tried disabling information_schema in config:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['DisableIS'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ShowDatabasesCommand'] = 'SHOW DATABASES';
```

But, get same error. Is there some workaround for this so that I can still use phpmyadmin to manage this database? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

-ron

Comment: I understand that my version of MySQL is old.  My question is:  Is there a workaround for using the lastest version of phpMyAdmin 4.0.8 with this older version of MySQL?

Comment: No,you need phpMyAdmin 2.11.

Comment: OK, looks like that's the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
show databases;
```

If this command doesnt show information_schema it means your mysql version is old.

I see yours is MySQL version 4,for INFORMATION_SCHEMA you need 5.